# How to fix AAPT: No resource identifier found for attribute 'appComponentFactory' in package 'android'?

Tags: android, react-native, gradle

The app builds without problem on iOS (some warnings, deprecated stuff, etc), but on android I cannot build the app and I get the following error :

> **android/app/build/intermediates/manifests/full/debug/AndroidManifest.xml:66:**
>
> **AAPT: No resource identifier found for attribute 'appComponentFactory' in package 'android**

The line refers to the following code :

```
<application
    android:name="com.facejob.MainApplication"
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:appComponentFactory="androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory"
    android:debuggable="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/iconapp"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/iconapp"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

Honestly, I don't know what to do. I already have read a lot of post about it and I cannot get this stuff working.

Comment: Find the `compileSdkVersion` line in one of your `build.gradle` files (in a typical Android app, it would be in `app/build.gradle` off of the project root, but I don't know what a React Native app might have). Then, set your `compileSdkVersion` to 28 -- right now, I think it is lower than that.

Comment: I'm having the same problem with an Ionic 3 project. Changing `compileSdkVersion` to 28 changed to this error: `AAPT: Color types not allowed (at 'statusBarBackground' with value '#000000')`

Comment: @CommonsWare When I change the compileSdkVersion I get the same error